Is it possible to declare an extern function without providing a body, then define it in another DLL?
I'm working on a C++ project where I want to declare a function in one DLL but define it in another. Specifically, I want to declare an extern function without providing a body (e.g., int MyFunction(); without { return 0; }) and then provide its actual implementation in a different DLL.
Is this possible, and if so, what would be the correct way to handle this?
Here’s a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:
// Header file (in DLL A)
extern int MyFunction();  // Declaration without a body

Then, in another DLL (DLL B):
// Source file (in DLL B)
int MyFunction() {
    return 42;  // Actual implementation
}

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, CMake, and C++23.

What did I try?
I declared the function as extern in one DLL without providing a body and attempted to define it in another DLL. I expected the linker to resolve the function during the build process.

What did I expect?
I expected the function to be resolved properly across DLLs, allowing the declaration in one DLL to be linked with the definition in another.

What actually happened?
However, the linker produced an error indicating that the function was not found, even though I had defined it in the other DLL. I'm not sure if I'm missing a specific configuration step for cross-DLL linking.

extern is redundant. Function declarations are extern by default.

To use a function across DLLs, you need to use __declspec(dllexport) in the DLL where the function is defined and __declspec(dllimport) similary in the DLL where the function is declared.
So something like this,
__declspec(dllimport) int MyFunction();


__declspec(dllexport) int MyFunction() {
    return 42;
}

Here is a link to another similar question about this.

I forgot to add that DLL B is compiled after DLL A
